# Bathroom behind meter box

Tags: bathroom, electrical-panel

We're thinking to have a bathroom fitted in our garage and understand that we'll need approval for it. However, our electricity meter box locates right behind the wall (on the external side). Does anyone know if there're rules regulating the distance between a bathroom (or kitchen?) and a meter box when it's on different sides of the wall? What are the typical rules in this regard?

Thanks

Edit: I'm in the UK. The garage is detached from the main house and the meter box contains just the electricity meter and the breaker panel for the garage building. The main house has its own breaker panel inside the house.

Comment: Electrical code varies by country, state, sometimes even city. Where in the world are you? Also, to be 100% certain, what are you calling a "meter box"? Is that just the pan with the meter base mounted to it? Is there an additional panel attached to the meter with a couple of breakers, or maybe all the breakers for your house? A picture of the "meter box" would be most helpful. If you're in the US, and the breaker panel is right on the other side of the wall, I'm 99% certain you're not allowed to have a breaker panel in a bathroom...

Comment: In the UK a meter box is a plastic box usually on an outside wall, containing the company fuse and the electricity meter. The breaker panel (consumer unit) may be elsewhere. But we need more information from the questioner to confirm their location.

Comment: I'm in the UK. The garage is detached from the main house and the meter box contains just the electricity meter and the breaker panel for the garage building. The main house has its own breaker panel inside the house.

Comment: Although I'm not in the US but the UK, I'd be curious to know what the rules are in the US. The panel is on the external wall though. I'm considering to take a more conservative approach.

Comment: I don't think having it on the outside wall will be a problem, but do need to check local codes.  The problem might come if the wires/conduit are inside of the wall and you need plumbing to go there also.  Code might allow them to be close, but I think common sense is to have them separated further away.  I am assuming modern plumbing and not dumping a honey pot out a window over the meter.